# Chrome loses my session data when returning from the payment gateway

Tags: javascript, php, forms, session, payment-gateway

Since the begining of August my users are presently losing their sessions whenever they use Chrome to perform a payment with Moneris. It works just fine under Firefox. The code hasn't change since a few years now, it all started automagically.

The payment "summary.php" page initially calls the gateway URL which then returns to the "return.php" page after the transaction. This return page just contains a form that grabs the transaction key and post it back to the gateway for verification purposes:

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script>
            function verify_transaction() {
                document.getElementById('verify').submit();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    
    <body onload="verify_transaction()">
        <form id="verify"  name="verify" action="https://www.gateway.com/verify.php" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="ps_store_id" value="abcdef">     
            <input type="hidden" name="hpp_key" value="abcdef">
            <input type="hidden" name="transactionKey" value="<?php echo $_POST['transactionKey'] ?>">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The issue here is that all the session data is gone when this page is called. I also cannot store the session anywhere as there are no ways for the gateway to send me back the information I would send to start with.

I am afraid it might have to do with the July release of Chrome which has this in the comments:
"Same Site Cookie policy changes are starting to roll out again"

Same thing for the August release:
"Rejection of insecure SameSite=None cookies" but I dont know how/where to go about this.

The web site is hosted on CPANEL and I made sure the user is using HTTPS all the way.

Does someone have a suggestion?

EDIT:

I just noticed that when I log in and out of the site, I get a lot of these:

"A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at https://google.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. It has been blocked, as Chrome now only delivers cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and [https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032."](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.%22)

Comment: `$_POST['transactionKey']` is actually not a session variable but a property from the POST request that would have sent the user to this page. Can you inspect the request in your Chrome developer tools (under the network tab) and see the exact details of the request to `return.php`?

Comment: Enable error reporting also.

Comment: I am sorry as I mistakenly said the POST was part of the session! So in this case I am actually able to fetch the transactionKey from the gateway and send it back but any reference to the user session is gone at this point.

Comment: Maybe you send the session id on a round trip to the payment gateway too. (Although you should be able to solve the cookie issue, but haven't really started investigating the problem yourself)

Comment: I actually spent 2 days alreayd trying to pinpoint the issue and this is where I am now. I however cannot send a session ID or any identifier to the payment gateway.

Comment: I am not seeing any errors under the Network tab, only 200s

Comment: I am able to fully reproduce this with Chrome on 3 separate sites using 2 separate payment gateways. Its as if the session is lost when the payment gateway returns back to the site after successful/decline postback. Seems to only affect Chrome

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['transactionKey'])) {
    $_SESSION['transKey'] = $_POST['transactionKey']; 
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script>
            function verify_transaction() {
                document.getElementById('verify').submit();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    
    <body onload="verify_transaction()">
        <form id="verify"  name="verify" action="https://www.gateway.com/verify.php" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="ps_store_id" value="abcdef">     
            <input type="hidden" name="hpp_key" value="abcdef">
            <input type="hidden" name="transactionKey" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['transKey']; ?>">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

after verify destroy the session.